# Does Introducing A pipe To my code Intoduces a Delay In Loading of components?

Tags: angular, rxjs

[Image of my Components without Using Pipes
Delay Here is:1300msec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WI3E.png)

[Image of my Components Using Pipes
Delay Here is:1400msec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8QUY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a pipe doesn't cause a delay worth mentioning. The delay is probably caused by the way the pipe is used in the component. If the pipe is called very often and does some expensive work, then this can cause a delay.

You need to provide the information (code, Plunker, ...) that allows to reproduce to be able to debug.